# Array Index out of Bounds in Eclipse

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I'm writing a program for Project Euler problem 3, which basically asks for the largest prime factor of 600851475143. While writing, I looked over all my code, but I repeatedly got an "Array Index out of Bounds" for Java. The error is at line 12, and here is the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class largestPrimeFactor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int [] woah = new int [9999];
        int [] nice = new int [9999];
        long number = 600851475143L; 
        for (int i = 1; i<999999999999L; i++){ 
            int placeHolder = i - 1;

            if (number%i==0){ 
                woah[placeHolder]=i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(woah));
    }
}
```

More specifically, it is at "woah[placeHolder] = i. Could anybody take a look at it for me and shoot me a solution?

I appreciate the help, but please do not suggest drastic changes to my code. I am just looking for a quick fix, nothing big that will force me to change my format. Thanks!

Comment: The code looks syntactically correct to me, please copy and paste the exact error message.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project? Have you tried quitting Eclipse and restarting it?

Comment: Intellij gives array out of bound at woah[placeHolder]=i;
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 59568
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:16)

Comment: @MichaelHobbs yes, i just realized that sorry. folkol here's the error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 59568
 at largestPrimeFactor.main(largestPrimeFactor.java:12)

Comment: As Kristine said change the size of you int array to fix this issue. This will not help you solve this problem. Your approach is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. You should generate a list of primes and then use that to find the prime factors. I was able to make your code work, see below:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Long> woah = new ArrayList<Long>();
        long number = 600851475143L;
        for (long i = 1; i< Math.sqrt(number); i=i+1){
            long placeHolder = i - 1;

            if (number%i==0L && isPrime(i)){
                woah.add(i);
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(long num) {
        if (num % 2 == 0 && num != 2) return false;
        for (int i = 3; i * i <= num; i += 2)
            if (num % i == 0) return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect! I ran it and the correct answer came out. Thank you so much!

Comment: When you have some time you can take a look at this: Spoiler Alert! https://github.com/MichaelLeeHobbs/ProjectEuler  I have about another 70 problems I need to convert to Java. Maybe I will get around to them someday ;)

Comment: I'll be sure to look over that time to time...thanks for everything you actually helped xD.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing the size of woah

int [] woah = new int [9999];

which is too small if you want to add something to index 59568

Answer (score 0):

```
package test;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class app {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Long> woah = new ArrayList<Long>();
        ArrayList<Long> nice = new ArrayList<Long>();
        Long number = 600851475143L;
        for (long i = 1; i<999999999999L; i=i+1){ 
            long placeHolder = i - 1;

            if (number%i==0L){ 
                System.out.println(i);
                woah.add(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(woah);
    }
}
```

Hey, I fixed your code, Regards. 8462696833 and still going ;) Interesting little problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that works. I already did that, but what I need is the largest prime factor, which is why I have two different arrays. (Probably not very efficient, but whatever.)

Comment: I ran the above code and the answer is in the list.

Comment: oh I didn't even think about the logic, just the compilation error, sorry about that